# select documents grouped by field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this documents of movie showing time and date:

```
`{
   "_id": ObjectId("5628668c3e82c49245b7acdc"),
   "ticketID": ObjectId("5606d36b5fbd7d76028b4b08"),
   "uid": "50000",
   "day": "Friday",
   "date": "2015-10-23 21:05:00",
   "adult": NumberLong(550),
   "student": NumberLong(550),
   "children": NumberLong(250),
   "limit": NumberLong(20),
   "sold": NumberLong(0) 
},{
   "_id": ObjectId("562866013e82c49045b7acdc"),
   "ticketID": ObjectId("5606d36b5fbd7d76028b4b08"),
   "uid": "50000",
   "day": "Friday",
   "date": "2015-10-23 19:30:00",
   "adult": NumberLong(1050),
   "student": NumberLong(800),
   "children": NumberLong(550),
   "limit": NumberLong(20),
   "sold": NumberLong(0) 
},{
   "_id": ObjectId("562865013e82c49845b7acda"),
   "ticketID": ObjectId("5606d36b5fbd7d76028b4b08"),
   "uid": "50000",
   "day": "Friday",
   "date": "2015-10-23 18:45:00",
   "adult": NumberLong(1500),
   "student": NumberLong(750),
   "children": NumberLong(750),
   "limit": NumberLong(20),
   "sold": NumberLong(0) 
}
`
```

I want to group the final result by "day" where "ticketID" matches, "date" as an object and adding "adult","student","children","limit" to an array

-- **UPDATE** --

I would like the returned structure to follow:

```
{
  "_id": "ticketID",
  "day": "Friday",
  "items": [
    {
      "date": date,
      "time": time"adult": price,
      "children": price,
      "student": price,
      "limit": value
    },
    {
      "date": date,
      "time": time"adult": price,
      "children": price,
      "student": price,
      "limit": value
    },
    {
      "date": date,
      "time": time"adult": price,
      "children": price,
      "student": price,
      "limit": value
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would like the returned structure to follow:

`{
"_id" : "ticketID",
"day" : "Friday"
"items" : [
    {
        "date" : date,
"time" : time
        "adult" : price,
"children" : price,
"student" : price,
"limit" : value
    },
    {
        "date" : date,
"time" : time
        "adult" : price,
"children" : price,
"student" : price,
"limit" : value
    },
    {
        "date" : date,
"time" : time
        "adult" : price,
"children" : price,
"student" : price,
"limit" : value
    }
]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following aggregation pipeline which uses the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator to group your documents by the specified fields, add the `items` array by using the accumulator operator **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** that returns an array of expression values for each group. The **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline operator then reshapes the documents by amending the fields to get the final desired structure:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "ticketID": "$ticketID",
                "day": "$day"
            },
            "items": {
                "$push": {
                    "date": "$date",
                    "time": "$time",
                    "adult": "$adult",
                    "children": "$children",
                    "student": "$student",
                    "limit": "$limit"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id.ticketID",
            "day": "$_id.day",
            "items": 1
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```